# LaTeX формулы на сайте

Tags: php, html, javascript

Добрый день! Подскажите, как сделать на сайте штуку с формулами. Забиваешь в див или спан латеховский код, а у клиента отображается скомпилированная картинка-формула? Как в википедии и прочих сайтах.

Comment: А вы посмотрите как это сделано на [математике](http://math.hashcode.ru).

Answer (score 1):

Вот это подойдёт? Там несколько способов. [Как вставить формулу LaTeX в блоге или на форуме](http://sovety.blogspot.com/2009/03/latex-formulas-in-blogs-and-on-web.html) .

Comment: Да! Спасибо огромное!!! :)